# How do you tell browser not to cache ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching

I make an ajax call to a .js file. The JS file is cached on mem-cache. At the moment chrome, Firefox and IE browsers are caching the ajax response. Is there any way to tell the browser not to cache the ajax response. Note - I still want the ajax call to get the mem-cached version of the JS file and not the version from servers so setting cache headers or adding a random value to ajax url will not work as it will bypass mem-cache.

**Note** - there are two types of caches. One is browser cache and the other is [memcached](http://memcached.org/) which is between my server and the browser. Every request to my server goes through memcache. I don't want to clear memcache I only want to clear browser cache.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How about adding timestamp to request parameters?

Comment: How are you initiating the ajax call? Are you using jQuery $.ajax? Regardless of how you're doing it, GET requests are cached by the browser. If you're using jQuery, you can set the cache: false to avoid this. Otherwise, you can try using a POST request to get the data, since those requests are not cached.

Comment: @Joel I am using jQuery. Setting cache: false adds _randomNumber to ajax url and as I said it will bypass mem-cache and hit my server. POST also does the same (bypasses mem-cache).

Comment: @webDeveloper Can you please clarify your question? You're loading a .js file via ajax? Based on how your request is worded, it sounds like you're saying you don't want to cache the file that's retrieved, but you want it to be retrieved from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the expiration for the caching from the web server serving those js files. You can read a bit more about the caching headers here: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter with a random value to the url, e.g.:

```
var url = "http://example.com/some_url/myjs.js?r=" + Math.random()
```

or

```
var url = "http://example.com/some_url/myjs.js?param1=value1&r=" + Math.random()
```

---

**Update:** If it bypasses your memcache like you said in a comment, you should check server-side conditions of reading memcache.